# Found eius but pēius in the same text: is it some kind of mistake?

Tags: classical-latin, vowel-quantity, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

While I was reading Lingua Latina per se Illustrata - Familia Romana, I noted something: the vocabulary list has ĕius but pēius, is that by accident? Also I noted *meī* as *mēī* in line 92 of chapter 25, but that one must be a typo.

Note that all other words have vowels noted long before /jj/ in the book, even though that's the length of the i (not of the vowel), as in *māius*.

Comment: Can you quote all of line 92 of chapter 24? At lines 91–92, I've got _Quīntus: "Ego canem iānitōris nōn vereor neque um­quam ab eō morsus sum."_

Comment: @BenKovitz sorry, I meant twenty-five.

Comment: Ah, there it is. I've found a few punctuation errors in LLPSI but never a macron error. Now I'm wondering if _Laetāminī, cīvēs mēī!_ might actually be correct somehow. ;)

Comment: @BenKovitz Yeah, there are some lowercase letters after "?" but only when there are repeating questions in succession, so I would say it's an editorial choice. And eius is the exception; they write Māius, pēior, Trōia, Trāiānum with a long vowel before the /jj/, so maybe it was Ørberg's dictionary, or something.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the e in *eius* could be long (normal) or short (see [Lewis & Short](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=is&filter=CUTF8)). The one in *peius* seems to be normally long as well. There can be quite a bit of irregularity in the length of vowels in Latin, especially in very common words such as pronouns.

Comment: OK. How would one pronounce them differently, though? Is the "i" in "eius" not doubled?

Comment: @SlayerGames44: I'm no expert on pronunciation, but I'd expect the i to be doubled in both cases. It's just the length of the vowel that's different (so not necessarily the length of the syllable).

Comment: Lewis and Short doesn't mark hidden quantity; it's mānsī, but they don't mark the A, even though they seem to mark it before /jj/ - Māius. Gaffiot marks all vowels short before /jj/, so eius and peius; Also L&S says it's *scanned* ĕius, just like it gives Ītalia for Italia because it's usually scanned as such - also given that the normal form is ēius and ĕius is found only in some earlier authors, I don't know what motivated Ørberg to make that choice

Comment: @SlayerGames44: You make some good points. Feel free to edit that into my text if you want.